# Laravel Syntax error, unexpected 'variable' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to access a Shopping Cart view of a user, but when I click to get the Cart View it throws the below error.

> Error : syntax error, unexpected 'item' (T_STRING)

**Button:**

```
<a href="{{ url('shopping-cart') }}"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Shopping Cart
    <span class="badge">{{ Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQty : '' }}</span>
</a>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/shopping-cart','ProductController@getCart');
```

**View**:

```
@if(Session::has('cart))
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach($products as $product)
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <span class="badge">{{ $product['qty'] }}</span>
                            <strong>{{ $product['item']['title'] }}</strong>
                            <span class="label label success">{{ $product['price'] }}</span>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    Action <span class="carret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="$">Reduce By 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="$">Reduce By All</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
@endif
```

**Cart Controller:**

```
public function getCart() {
    if(!Session::has('cart')) {
        return view('shop.shopping-cart');
    }
    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    return view('shop.shopping-cart', ['products' => $cart->items, 'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@if(Session::has('cart))`

There is a typo here.

Comment: oh damn it, now one quotation wasted my 1 hour great! It worked @vuldo

Comment: No problem, you should use an IDE that's spot this type of mistakes

Comment: I'm using Brackets @Vuldo

Comment: Try to see if there is a plugin for `blade` templating, since I think that's why it didn't spotted it

Answer (score 1):

You missed  a ' in the view

```
 @if(Session::has('cart))
```

You need to correct it

```
@if(Session::has('cart'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You left to put a `'` at the first line of your View. it must be:

`@if(Session::has('cart'))`

Comment: I am glad this helped you.